# Saving a list from __main__

Tags: python-3.x, class, namespaces, tuples

Determined solution: It should be noted that it should be as simple as when iterating it to be appendage to a list... However, it should be noted that the big issue of why this was not working for me is that I was using and IDE( Spyder 4.1.3) and when I ran the code it did not execute my desired output. However, if I save it into a py script and execute, it does not have issues appending the data through the iteration...

The take away is if using an IDE and run through issues test through executing whole script to rule out IDE bug.

I have a class that I am suppose to utilize to parse some data out. I successfully used it and have created a variable that saves the output of this class. I can use a for loop to see the parsed data but I am unable to save them to an actual list. Could someone help me get this data out?

```
Class: 

     You can use this code and put it in your own script
class ParseFastQ(object):
    """Returns a read-by-read fastQ parser analogous to file.readline()"""
    def __init__(self,filePath,headerSymbols=['@','+']):
        """Returns a read-by-read fastQ parser analogous to file.readline().
        Exmpl: parser.__next__()
        -OR-
        Its an iterator so you can do:
        for rec in parser:
            ... do something with rec ...
        rec is tuple: (seqHeader,seqStr,qualHeader,qualStr)
        """
        if filePath.endswith('.gz'):
            self._file = gzip.open(filePath)
        else:
            self._file = open(filePath, 'rU')
        self._currentLineNumber = 0
        self._hdSyms = headerSymbols     
    def __iter__(self):
        return self

def __next__(self):
    """Reads in next element, parses, and does minimal verification.
    Returns: tuple: (seqHeader,seqStr,qualHeader,qualStr)"""
    # ++++ Get Next Four Lines ++++
    elemList = []
    for i in range(4):
        line = self._file.readline()
        self._currentLineNumber += 1 ## increment file position
        if line:
            elemList.append(line.strip('\n'))
        else: 
            elemList.append(None)

    # ++++ Check Lines For Expected Form ++++
    trues = [bool(x) for x in elemList].count(True)
    nones = elemList.count(None)
    # -- Check for acceptable end of file --
    if nones == 4:
        raise StopIteration
    # -- Make sure we got 4 full lines of data --
    assert trues == 4,\
           "** ERROR: It looks like I encountered a premature EOF or empty line.\n\
           Please check FastQ file near line number %s (plus or minus ~4 lines) and try again**" % (self._currentLineNumber)
    # -- Make sure we are in the correct "register" --
    assert elemList[0].startswith(self._hdSyms[0]),\
           "** ERROR: The 1st line in fastq element does not start with '%s'.\n\
           Please check FastQ file near line number %s (plus or minus ~4 lines) and try again**" % (self._hdSyms[0],self._currentLineNumber) 
    assert elemList[2].startswith(self._hdSyms[1]),\
           "** ERROR: The 3rd line in fastq element does not start with '%s'.\n\
           Please check FastQ file near line number %s (plus or minus ~4 lines) and try again**" % (self._hdSyms[1],self._currentLineNumber) 
    # -- Make sure the seq line and qual line have equal lengths --
    assert len(elemList[1]) == len(elemList[3]), "** ERROR: The length of Sequence data and Quality data of the last record aren't equal.\n\
           Please check FastQ file near line number %s (plus or minus ~4 lines) and try again**" % (self._currentLineNumber) 

    # ++++ Return fatsQ data as tuple ++++
    return tuple(elemList)
```

#

Call this class to make variable:

```
fastqfile=ParseFastQ('filepath')
```

I then wanted to determine what class it was since it did not let me extract parsed fasqdata

```
In: type(fastqfile)
Out: __main__.ParseFastQ
```

This part of code will let me print put all output

```
for fastq_obj in fastqfile:
    #This is the header
    print(fastq_obj[0])
```

I attempted to extract that data and save in a list...

```
seqHeader=[]
for fastq_obj in fastqfile:
    #This is the header
    seqHeader.append(print(fastq_obj[0]))
```

I also attempted .extend and nothing was saved

Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
seqHeader=[]
for fastq_obj in fastqfile:
    #This is the header
    seqHeader.append(fastq_obj[0])

# look at the seqHeader list
print(seqHeader)
```

I really can't understand why did you pass `print()` func inside append. `print()` func returns nothing, so nothing can be appended in the list.

Comment: I actually attempted seqHeader.append(fastq_obj[0]) and it gave me an empty list. I used print because when I did print(fastq_obj[0]), it showed me the list.

Comment: the code suggested, ive ran previously and does not work

Comment: i've added a print statement at the end of loop... make this change and run it

Comment: can you update the question with the output shown for the 2nd block from bottom ?? ( the one with only print statement inside loop)